# Robot Framework Telnet Connection retry

Tags: python, testing, telnet, robotframework

Sometimes I got

```
> error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

and then all my test fail. Looking for a way to force the telnet to retry few times.

This is how my connection command looks like:

```
> Telnet.Open Connection ${IP} \ \ \ \r None
```

Comment: Can you post some telnet connection code from your tests?

Comment: Telnet.Open Connection    ${IP}    \    \    \    \r    None

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Wait Until Keyword Succeeds](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Wait%20Until%20Keyword%20Succeeds). For example, you could have it try every 15 seconds for two minutes like this:

```
Example
    Wait until keyword succeeds    2 minutes    15 seconds
    \ Telnet.Open Connection ${IP} \ \ \ \r None
```

Answer (score 1):

For loop should work:

```
: FOR    ${counter}    IN RANGE     3
    \    ${success}=   Run Keyword And Return Status   Telnet.Open Connection      ${IP}
    \    Exit For Loop If   ${success}
```